# InvalidInput: Route 53 does not support custom CloudWatch metric statistics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, pulumi, cloudwatch-alarms

I am trying to create an AWS route53 health checkAlarm using pulumi and it keeps giving error as "InvalidInput: Route 53 does not support custom CloudWatch metric statistics"

```
const autoFailoverPrimary = new aws.route53.HealthCheck("prd198-Primary", {
cloudwatchAlarmName: "prd198-custom-alarm",
cloudwatchAlarmRegion: "us-east-1,
insufficientDataHealthStatus: "Unhealthy",
type: "CLOUDWATCH_METRIC",
 });

"prd198-custom-alarm" using custom metric
const otHealthCheck = new aws.cloudwatch.MetricAlarm("prd198-custom-alarm", {
    alarmDescription: "service is down",
    comparisonOperator: "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold",
    evaluationPeriods: 1,
    insufficientDataActions: [],
    datapointsToAlarm: 1,
    okActions: [],
    alarmActions: [],
    metricQueries: [
        {
            id: "m1",
            returnData: true,
            metric: {
                dimensions: {
                    ERRORCODE: "500",
                },
                metricName: "ERRORS",
                namespace: "prd198-custom",
                period: 120,
                stat: "Sum",
            },
        },
    ],
    threshold: 1,
});
```

I am using putMetricData API to send the dimensions.

Comment: What's different about the production account and the account(s) that the QA/branch environments are in? Different regions etc? Pulumi's going to be calling the same APIs so if the only difference is the account, then I suggest you start by looking there

Comment: Both QA and Prod are in us-east-1

Comment: Any other differences? What I'm getting at is that if you're running the same code and trying to deploy the same resources and getting different results, there's something different about the setup in the account

Comment: It is just i got the same problem in QA and refresh 2-3 times and it worked. But in production same code throws error as it is

Comment: @PiersKarsenbarg I tried with another custom metric alarm it throws the same error. How we can create route 53 health check using the custom metric alarm.